# Unhandled Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

During the write automation test in selenium, I received Unhandled Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException for line which uses "wait"

```
   public static void clickFirstAccountDetails() {
        getDriver().switchTo().frame(0);
        getDriver().wait(5000);
        getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText("Xyz")).click();
    }
```

**Unhandled Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException**

Other methods like switchTo, findElement are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a compiler error in java to not explicitly deal with a so-called checked exception, and InterruptedException is checked. The solution is fortunately quite simple:

Just add the exception to your throws line. In fact, for any test code, feel free to just tack `throws Exception` at the end of it. A test method that throws is treated as a failed test which is almost always precisely what you want to happen, and this way, every detail that is available in the exception will end up in your test report, also what you usually want. So, update the first line to read:

```
public static void clickFirstAccountDetails throws Exception {
```

and that'll fix it. You may want to do:

```
public static void clickFirstAccountDetails throws InterruptedException {
```

instead if you prefer to continue to get compiler errors when you expand your test code and include calls to code that throws other checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

wait() method throws InterruptedException that is why you are getting Unhandled Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException

```
public static void clickFirstAccountDetails() {
        getDriver().switchTo().frame(0);
        try{
           getDriver().wait(5000);
          }catch(InterruptedException){}
        getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText("Xyz")).click();
    }
```

you can use try catch (Exception handling)